# Even the most simple query takes half a second on to any table

Tags: mysql, performance

I created an Innodb table with a id and name column and running this query

```
insert into test (name) VALUES('test');
```

takes .5 seconds

even

```
SELECT id FROM test LIMIT 1
```

or

```
select 1
```

takes .5 seconds or so

Any suggestions on where I can read more about how to improve the speed would be helpful. I would imagine these queries shouldn't take more than .05 seconds or so. Restarting the server and check/repair/analyze didn't help.

Is there such a thing as checking the base query time? i.e. the fastest a query can run? I wonder if it's the server being slow, the load averages doesn't say that it's being over utilized.

I am using mysql query browser to test these statements.

Comment: What's the rtt if you ping (the command line tool) the mysql machine ?

Comment: The ping average is 73ms

Answer (score 2):

How far is your client away from the server (network-wise)?   If "select 1" is taking 0.5 seconds, it might be that your round trip to the database server is about 0.5s.

Comment: I am surprised query time isn't reported separately from the latency time.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT 1` should have been nearly instant. I would suggest checking to see if something else is using up CPU cycles or something on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to shell on that server?  Log into mysql from the command line locally and try a few commands from there.

Next probably want to look at latency, how far are you from this server if its remote?